# AttributeError 'AccountForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create user model with authorization by email (using Django 1.7 Python 3.4). I've created custom user model with admin class. But when I'm trying to edit user instance in django admin panel I'm getting an error:

AttributeError at /admin/accounts/account/1/
'AccountForm' object has no attribute 'get'

I can modify users data without problems by django model API, troubles appears just with admin panel. Traceback says that with email field something wrong, but I'cant realize what indeed.

```
/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict


    return attrs
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    """
    Given a dictionary of data and this widget's name, returns the value
    of this widget. Returns None if it's not provided.
    """
    return data.get(name, None) ...
def id_for_label(self, id_):
    """
    Returns the HTML ID attribute of this Widget for use by a <label>,
    given the ID of the field. Returns None if no ID is available.

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
name    
'email'
data    
<django.forms.widgets.AccountForm object at 0x7f19280790b8>
files   
{}
self    
<django.contrib.admin.widgets.AdminEmailInputWidget object at 0x7f1928039a58>
```

**My Code:**

```
models.py:
class AccountManager ( BaseUserManager ) :
    '''  '''
    def _create_user ( self, email, password, is_staff = False, is_superuser = False, **extra_fields ) :
        ''' Creates a User with given email and password '''
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email :
            raise ValueError( 'wrong email' )
        email = self.normalize_email( email )
        user = self.model( email = email, is_staff = is_staff, is_superuser = is_superuser,
                           last_login = now, date_joined = now, **extra_fields )
        user.set_password( password )
        user.save( using = self._db )

        return user


    def create_user ( self, email, password = None, **extra_fields ) :
        '''  '''
        return self._create_user( email, password = None, **extra_fields )


    def create_superuser ( self, email, password, **extra_fields ) :
        '''  '''
        return self._create_user( email, password, is_staff = True, is_superuser = True, is_admin = True, **extra_fields )



class Account ( AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin ) :
    ''' Custom user account inherits from both AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin '''
    email       = models.EmailField( max_length = 255, unique = True, db_index = True, verbose_name = 'email' )
    first_name  = models.CharField( max_length = 255, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'name' )
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length = 255, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'last name' )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField( default = timezone.now )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [ 'first_name' ]

    is_active = models.BooleanField( default = True )
    is_admin  = models.BooleanField( default = False )
    is_staff  = models.BooleanField( default = False )

    objects = AccountManager()


    class Meta :
        '''  '''
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'


    def get_full_name ( self ) :
        '''  '''
        full_name = '{} {}'.format( self.first_name, self.second_name )

        return full_name.strip()


    def get_short_name ( self ) :
        '''  '''
        return self.first_name


    def email_user ( self, subject, message, from_email = None ) :
        '''  '''
        send_mail( subject, message, from_email, [self.email] )


    def __str__ ( self ) :
        '''  '''
        return self.email 


forms.py
User = get_user_model()


class AccountCreationForm ( UserCreationForm ) :
    '''  '''
    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kargs ) :
        super( AccountCreationForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kargs )
        del self.fields[ 'username' ]


    class Meta :
        '''  '''
        model = User
        fields = ( 'email', )



class AccountChangeForm ( UserChangeForm ) :
    '''  '''
    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kargs ) :
        '''  '''
        super( AccountChangeForm, self ).__init__( self, *args, **kargs )
        del self.fields[ 'username' ]


    class Meta :
        '''  '''
        model = User
        fields = ( 'email', )


admin.py
User = get_user_model()

class AccountAdmin ( UserAdmin ) :
    '''  '''
    form = AccountChangeForm
    add_form = AccountCreationForm

    list_display = ( 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name' )
    ordering = ( 'email', )
    list_filter = ( 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups' )
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name' )
    filter_horizontal = ( 'groups', 'user_permissions', )
    ordering = ( 'email', )
    fieldsets = (
        ( None, { 'fields': ( 'email', 'password') } ),
        ( 'Personal info', { 'fields': ( 'first_name', 'last_name' ) } ),
        ( 'Permissions', { 'fields': ( 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions' ) } ),
        ( 'Important dates', { 'fields': ( 'last_login', 'date_joined' ) } ),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        ( None, {
            'classes': ( 'wide', ),
            'fields': ( 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2' ) }
        ),
    )


admin.site.register( User, AccountAdmin )
```

Full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/account/1/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'home',
 'accounts')
Installed Middleware:
('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  567.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1440.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1428.             errors=helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py" in __init__
  349.             self.extend(list(six.itervalues(form.errors)))
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  154.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  353.         self._clean_fields()
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  362.             value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
File "/home/oleshko/design/.virtualenvs/begemotik/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  228.         return data.get(name, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/accounts/account/1/
Exception Value: 'AccountForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please post the actual traceback - what you have posted is not useful. If you see the debug page, click "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and paste that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took an example from docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/
and it suddenly start working.
If all tried and nothing helps - see the instructions!!!